# how to prevent NHibernate running an "Audit Login" on configuration

Tags: nhibernate

When i configure NHibernate it seems to do an

```
Audit Login
-- network protocol: LPC
set quoted_identifier on
set arithabort off
set numeric_roundabort off
set ansi_warnings on
set ansi_padding on
set ansi_nulls on
set concat_null_yields_null on
set cursor_close_on_commit off
set implicit_transactions off
set language British
set dateformat dmy
set datefirst 1
set transaction isolation level read committed
```

presumably to check that the supplied connectionstring is valid.

Is there a way to turn this behaviour off?

I'm running some unit tests to check that my application bootstraps without error, but this behaviour is requiring me to have a real database.

All my integration tests use SQLite, so this isnt a problem in that situation.

Thanks